# How to start Node.js app in Jelastic cloud

Tags: node.js, cloud, bitbucket, jelastic

I have tried to host my node.js app in jelastic cloud and get problem. My app works without any problem locally.I deploy it to jelastic over git repo (I push commit to private bitbucket repo, repo credentials registered in jelastic, so app should be deployed to cloud). My main app file (server.js) located in the root of repo and my pakage.json  looks like this:

```
 {
  "name": "folserver",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Server side for my app",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "~0.0.3",
    "urlencode": ">=0",
    "json-middleware": ">=0",
    "moment": ">=0",
    "express": "^4.9.5",
    "mongodb": "~1.3.9",
    "needle": "0.7.8",
    "async": ">=0",
    "bunyan": ">=0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^2.0.1",
    "should": "^4.3.0",
    "supertest": "^0.15.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha   --require should --reporter spec -A --recursive --ui bdd testcases/tests.js",
    "start": "set NODE_ENV=production&&node server.js"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "author": "PainKiller",
  "private": true
}
```

. But app crushes with this error (I can see it in node/node/log file):

```
 Fri Mar 27 2015 09:54:30 GMT+0000 (UTC): Starting application 'nodejs' ... Script = server.js Script Args = Node Options = 
 module.js:340 throw err; ^Error: Cannot find module '/opt/repo/ROOT/server.js' at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15) at Function.Module._load
 (module.js:280:25) at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10) at startup (node.js:119:16) at node.js:906:3
```

As far as I can see Jelastic just can't find main file of my application. When I requested jelastic support, they said problem isn't related to their service, it's just application problem and I should ask help at specialized forums.So stackoverflow is my last hope. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hello [@Dmitry Malugin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2745961/dmitry-malugin),

I've like to recommend you to visit the [Jelastic Docs](http://docs.jelastic.com/) site where you also can find Node.js Deploying Tutorials. It will be helpful for you to understanding how to the Node.js working with Jelastic.

These tutorials you can find by the following link - http://docs.jelastic.com/nodejs-tutorials

Comment: Firstly,  I know how to start my app in Jelastic Cloud, and now I do it by uploading zip archive and everything works fine. When I try to deploy my app over GIT I have a failure, nothing working and there are no files in /opt/repo/ROOT folder. I had week long conversation with support, I provided credentials for GIT account and detailed information with screenshots about my actions, ok If it's my fault, show me where I am wrong. Nothing just links to docs and silence. I still can't use this option.

Comment: @DmitryMalugin, seems you've entered your credentials incorrectly.

Correct:
URL: https://bitbucket.org/ProjectName/proj.git
Branch: master
Login: mylogin
Password: mypassword

Incorrect:
URL: https://mylogin@bitbucket.org/ProjectName/proj.git
Branch: master
Login: mylogin
Password: mypassword

When you suggest two login names in the settings you get an incorrect host and your deployment will be failed.

Comment: Thanks alot, it solved problem, It would be nice if jelastic thow out a meaningful error in this case. Again thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

I think should properly set NODE_PATH environment variable.